# Describe operators over Euclidean vector space, that are self-adjoint with respect to any inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to describe all the linear operators over Euclidean vector space, that are self-adjoint with any inner product. Formally, I must find all the $\phi : V \rightarrow V$ s.t. $\forall a,b \in V$ and any inner product holds the following $(\phi(a), b) = (a, \phi(b))$.

I've tried to solve it, rewriting it in a matrix form: $x^TA^TGy=x^TGAy$, where $G$ and $A$ are Gram matrix and matrix form of $\phi$ in some basis respectively. From that point I came to reformulating the problem into "describe all matrices A, that satisfies $(GA)^T = GA$, where G is a Gram matrix for any inner product", but had no luck to go any further, than find some trivial examples like $\lambda I, \lambda \in R$.

Do I miss something important from which I can start?

Comment: We're assuming $\phi$ is a linear operator, right?

Comment: Do you mean to find all self-adjoint operators with respect to a *given* inner product? Or do you wish to find self-adjoiint operators with respect to *every* inner product. Notice that the second statement would mean that you take any inner product, $\varphi$ will be self-adjoint. On the other hand, the first one means you fix an inner product first, and then find all $\varphi$'s that are self-adjoint.

Comment: You can actually easily calculate it through in the 2-dimensional case and see, that indeed the matrices $\lambda I$ are the only ones to satisfy this property. I assume that the same will be true in higher dimensions

Comment: @StiftungWarentest You would be correct. It ends up being similar to the proof that the only matrices that commute with all other matrices are $\lambda I$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog sure, it is a linear operator, forgot to add it

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I mean with respect to every inner product

Comment: @StiftungWarentest thank you, I'll try it